# Требуется помощь с generics

Tags: typescript, generics, типы

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Есть часть кода, где формируется `usersIds`:

```
//some code here...

const usersIds: MapObject<string[]> = employees.items.reduce((r, employee) => {
                    const org = getLinkedObject<Organization>(employee, 'organization');
                    if(!r[org.dns])
                        r[org.dns] = [];

                    r[org.dns].push(employee.userid);
                    return r
                }, {});


                if (!isEmpty(usersIds)) {
                    const groupsNames: GroupsNamesType = await this.fetchGroupsNames(usersIds);

//some code here...

interface MapObject<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}
```

В нём вызывается `fetchGroupsNames`, куда этот `usersIds` передаётся. А вот сам `fetchGroupsNames`, где принимается `users` и вызывается `fetchUsersGroups` (который менять нельзя, он принимает только `users: string[]`). Как привести `MapObject<string[]>` к типу `string[]` в месте, где я указал на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. я попробовал так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не думаю, что это хорошая идея...

Comment: Что из себя представляет тип GroupsNamesType?

Comment: @skubarenko interface GroupsNamesType {
    [key: string]: string[];
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо разобраться с тем, какой тип вы в действительности хотите использовать.
Дело в том, что `usersIds` - это объект, судя по описанию интерфейса `MapObject` и по тому как вы его формируете.

`fetchUsersGroups` же, как вы заметили, принимает в качестве аргумента массив, соответственно у вас есть два варианта:

1. Изначально формировать массив, а не объект. Но насколько это можно понять из вашего кода, вам всё таки-необходимы ключи `org.dns`, а значит, этот вариант не подходит.
2. Вытащить из `usersIds` все идентификаторы пользователей в массив. Скорее всего, именно это ваш вариант.

Сделать это можно так:

```
function getIds<T>(src: MapObject<T[]>) {
    const result = [];

    for (const key in src) {
        result.push(...src[key]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Или, если вам нравится функциональный подход, вот так:

```
function getIds<T>(src: MapObject<T[]>) {
    return Object.keys(src).reduce((acc: T[], key) => [...acc, ...src[key]], []);
}
```

В обоих случаях результат `getIds` можно будет передавать в качестве аргумента в `fetchUsersGroups`

Answer (score 1):

Да, `as any` - плохая идея, вы обманываете компилятор. В рантайме у вас будет ошибка, т.к. функция `fetchUsersGroups` ожидает массив, а вы передаете ей объект.
Я не знаю требования бизнес-логики, поэтому покажу как можно решить в целом проблему.
Нам необходимо получить все группы по массиву юзеров, массив юзеров мы соберем из инстанса `MapObject`: пройдемся по свойствам объекта, и соберем один массив из других:

```
protected async fetchGroupNames(users: MapObject<string[]>): Promise<GroupNameType> {
  try {
    const usersArr = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(users).reduce((res: string[], propertyName) => { 
        res.push(...users[propertyName]);
        return res;
    }, []);
    return await this.usersManagementUsers.fetchUsersGroups(usersArr)
  }
  catch (e) {
     // ...
  }
}
```